# Difference between = and == and comparison of nans

Tags: ocaml

I need to write a function which detects when a number passed into it is undefined or not. In ocaml toplevel I've discovered something interesting.

```
nan = nan;;
```

This evaulates to false. But later I've found out something even more peculiar

```
nan == nan;;
```

Evaluates to true. What is the difference between = and == and why the first comparison returns false when comparing two nans with themselves?

Comment: IEEE defines that `NaN` is not equal to any other number, including itself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @Colonel Thirty Two says, it is standard behavior for NaN not to be equal to itself. (Whether this is a good idea is a separate debate.)

It's not true that NaN values are always physically equal:

```
# let x = 0.0 /. 0.0;;
val x : float = nan
# x == nan;;
- : bool = false
```

Physical equality `==` is a tricky and implementation-dependent notion. Roughly speaking, it tests for sharing of values, which is supposed to be undetectable for immutable values like nan. You should only use it in your programs if you know exactly what you're doing.

**Update**

You can test for NaN using `compare`:

```
# let is_nan x = compare x nan = 0;;
val is_nan : float -> bool = <fun>
# is_nan nan;;
- : bool = true
# is_nan (1.0 /. 0.0);;
- : bool = false
# is_nan (0.0 /. 0.0);;
- : bool = true
```

Answer (score 3):

NaN is specified as different to any number, including itself. This is because it may have several representations.

Your == works here because it verifies that the two values share the same memory-zone. That wouldn't be the case if you "produced" a NaN from your computations.

The right way to detect your variable's NaN-ness can be with that tiny function:

```
let is_nan x = FP_nan = classify_float x
```